# How to make spring-data-envers work with Hibernate 3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I am trying to implement Entity Auditing functionality using spring-data-envers. The problem is my company is still using Hibernate 3, and it looks like spring-data-envers only work with Hibernate 4. The following are the error I got:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: You need to install the org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener class as post insert, update and delete event listener.; nested exception is org.hibernate.envers.exception.AuditException: You need to install the org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener class as post insert, update and delete event listener.
    at org.hibernate.envers.AuditReaderFactory.get(AuditReaderFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.envers.AuditReaderFactory.get(AuditReaderFactory.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support.EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl.findRevisions(EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:414)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:399)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.findRevisions(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support.RepositoryIntegrationTest.returnsEmptyRevisionsForUnrevisionedEntity(RepositoryIntegrationTest.java:99)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try following configuration

in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

in spring-hibernate.xml ( or whatever name you gave )

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>com.yourpackage.model</value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
</property>
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">replace_with_your_</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show.sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format.sql}</prop>

        <!-- Envers properties -->
        <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.auditTablePrefix"/>            
        <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.auditTableSuffix">_HISTORY</prop>            
    </props>
</property>
```

Important line:

```
<prop key="org.hibernate.envers.auditTablePrefix"></prop>
<prop key="org.hibernate.envers.auditTableSuffix">_HISTORY</prop>
```

The suffix '_HISTORY' is the name you choose to give to database table that will hold different versions of you entity. And last one `@Audited` annotation, is placed on top of your entities that need to be audited.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Audited
public class User implements Serializable {}
```

Comment: Where you register those Hibernate Envers events?

Comment: Events are registered in database. Hibernate Envers will create a table for each audited entity.

Comment: I think start from Hibernate Envers 4 there is no need to register events from your project. But not Hibernate Envers 3 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Spring Java Config in my project that make the spring-data-envers works:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your.repository.package", repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class ServiceModelTestSpringConfig {

//.. Spring-JPA-Hibernate setup ..
 @Bean
 public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
   em.setDataSource(dataSource());
   em.setPackagesToScan("your.entity.package");

   JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
   em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
   em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

   return em;
 }

 @Bean
 public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
   JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
   transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

   return transactionManager;
 }

 @Bean
 public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
   return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
 }

 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() {
   DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
   dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
   // dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"); // Use in-memory database
   dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:~/test/itdata;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"); // Use file database
   dataSource.setUsername("ying");
   return dataSource;
 }

 Properties additionalProperties() {
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
   properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "false");
   properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
   // Hibernate Envers Event Listeners
   properties.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert", "org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener");
   properties.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.event.post-update", "org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener");
   properties.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete", "org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener");
   properties.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update", "org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener");
   properties.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove", "org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener");
   properties.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate", "org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener");
   return properties;
 }
 // .. EOF Spring-JPA-Hibernate setup ..

}
```